# GEE: Annual frequency maps

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to create **annual** Landsat frequency maps. So the purpose would be to see, what is the percentage of occurrence of index 1

1. I would like to count all images per year
2. I would like to count images where the index values equal 1 (per year)
3. Finally, create annual maps which show (question2/question1)*100 per pixel

I know how to create an annual reduce mean function, but I don't know how to add multiple reduce functions inside it if it is necessary.

```js
var yearly= ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    years.map(function(y) {
      return collection 
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .set('year', y)
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your reducer, it's hard to offer any concrete solution, but a general sketch is: you map a function to apply whatever transformations you need to your images (e.g. thresholding), then apply a [combined reducer](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#combine-reducers).

Comment: Thank you! That I was looking for!